# How to hide "Resources" tab from Google Chrome Developer Console?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, console, resources

Is there any possibility to Restrict opening this part of Browser's inspector? I hope there will be something which can help me to hide when my web page loads.

![Google Chrome Developer Console][1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to hide your website loading from the developer console.

Why do you want to do this? I cannot think of any legitimate reason to do this.

Comment: Reasons:
My website contains photographs, I don't want to watermark them. I don't know what is the other method to protect those images other than Right click protect and things like that. But still if a client knows about the Resource Tab, he/she can easily pull images from my website.

Basically Insecurity is my concern.

Comment: You can only ever make it harder to download. But really, you are putting them on a website, so anyone visiting that site has to download them to view them. Make a visible statement nearby that clearly reminds the visitors that you have the copyright.

Comment: No, because the client/browser saves their own copy of the image, which they can do whatever they want to with. They could also screenshot the website, so there is no way to avoid it except by not publishing in the first place, if they ignore copyright.